# Guide to Art of the Fugue?

Tags: fugue

I'm looking for a thorough, perhaps measure-by-measure, analysis of Bach's *Art of the Fugue* (*Die Kunst der Fuge,* BWV 1080). Is there a book, journal article, thesis, or dissertation which does this?

Comment: http://store.doverpublications.com/048649764x.html, maybe.

Comment: What's to analyze? It's a fugue.

Comment: @Ricky It's **considerably** more than one fugue...

Comment: Just for information: Apparently Douglas Hofstadter's book "Gödel, Escher, Bach"... has a lot to say about this piece. But it's not a conventional analysis as such, and goes into many other things apparently unconnected with music...

Comment: @Andy: Okay, it's a bunch of fugues. It's still just an exercise in contrapuntal composition. There's been some major developments in that area since then, especially in opera. Precedence isn't the same as excellence.

Comment: Ah. Bach lacked excellence? I'm curious about those developments since, especially in opera. I'm fairly familiar with contrapuntal writing up to, say, Dallapiccola. I would have said that there was very little new in contrapuntal technique, and none of it any better handled than in Bach (although not necessarily handled worse), but I can stand to learn something new.

Answer (score 4):

Laurence Dreyfus, *Bach and the Patterns of Invention* (Cambridge, MA: Harvard University Press, 1996)

David Yearsley, *Bach and the Meanings of Counterpoint* (Cambridge: Cambridge University Press, 2010)

Peter Schleuning, *Johann Sebastian Bachs Kunst der Fuge: Ideologie, Entstehung, Analyse* (Munich: DTV, 1993)

Heinrich Adel, *Bach's Die Kunst der Fuge: a living compendium of fugal procedures, with a motivic analysis of all the fugues* (Lanham, MD: University Press of America, 1993)

Göncz, Zoltán; Laki, Péter; Mészáros, Erzsébet, *Bach's testament: On the philosophical and theological background of The art of fugue* (Lanham, MD: Scarecrow Press, 2013)

For hundreds more citations, visit http://www.rilm.org, the international catalog of literature about music.

Comment: And don't forget Donald Tovey's Companion - he was very shrewd about how the counterpoint worked.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for something you can source, maybe https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~repercus/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/repercussions-Vol.-9-No.-1-Markham-Michael-The-Usefulness-of-Such-Artworks.pdf

a website that might be informative, http://www.flagmusic.com/aof.php?r=aof_c_ii